# How do I store mp4 file as Data or NSData object in iOS?

Tags: ios, nsdata, mp4, cloudkit, ckasset

How would I store media of type mp4 as an object of Data or NSData in iOS? I need to do this as a step toward saving the mp4 file as a CKAsset in CloudKit.

I would like to do what [this post on stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969341/how-to-properly-send-an-image-to-cloudkit-as-ckasset) does with an image object, except I want to do it with an mp4 file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried this, but maybe the `Data` initializer that takes a URL would do the trick:

`init(contentsOf:options:)`

E.g.:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"myFile", withExtension:"mp4")
let data = Data(contentsOf: url)
```

[See the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/3126626-init)