# How can I save an image using CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cloudkit

I've run into a problem saving images using iCloud. After following a few tutorials I was able to save and fetch records containing strings from iCloud but I can't figure out how to do the same with images. Here is some of my code below so that maybe someone can help me figure out what to do next. Any help is appreciated!

```
// saving to cloud

static func save(user: AppUser, completion: @escaping (Result<AppUser, Error>) -> ()) {
        let userRecord = CKRecord(recordType: RecordType.User)
        userRecord["displayName"] = user.displayName as CKRecordValue
        userRecord["pfp"] = user.pfp as CKRecordValue // <-- **not sure if this is right?**
        userRecord["username"] = user.username as CKRecordValue
        userRecord["password"] = user.password as CKRecordValue
        userRecord["bio"] = user.bio as CKRecordValue
        
        CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.save(userRecord) { (record, err) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let err = err {
                    completion(.failure(err))
                    return
                }
                guard let record = record else {
                    completion(.failure(CloudFuncUserError.recordFailure))
                    return
                }
                let recordID = record.recordID
                guard let displayName = record["displayName"] as? String else {
                    completion(.failure(CloudFuncUserError.castFailure))
                    return
                }
                guard let pfp = record["pfp"] as? CKAsset else {
                    completion(.failure(CloudFuncUserError.castFailure))
                    return
                } // <-- **not sure if this is right?**
                guard let username = record["username"] as? String else {
                    completion(.failure(CloudFuncUserError.castFailure))
                    return
                }
                guard let password = record["password"] as? String else {
                    completion(.failure(CloudFuncUserError.castFailure))
                    return
                }
                guard let bio = record["bio"] as? String else {
                    completion(.failure(CloudFuncUserError.castFailure))
                    return
                }
                let appUser = AppUser(recordID: recordID, displayName: displayName, pfp: pfp, username: username, password: password, bio: bio)
                completion(.success(appUser))
            }
        }
    }
```

initialization

```
@main
struct TestForReleaseApp: App {
    
    var user = appUser()
    var isUser = AppUser(displayName: "", pfp: CKAsset <-- (this is a placeholder, I don't know what goes here), username: "", password: "", bio: "")
    var posts = Posts()
    var post = Post(displayName: "", username: "", content: "", createdAt: Date(), star: 0, stared: 0, repost: 0, reposted: 0, share: 0, shared: 0, comment: 0, commented: 0, comments: [""], isPublic: 0, isPremium: 0)
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(post: post, user: isUser, appUser: user).environmentObject(user).environmentObject(posts).preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969341/how-to-properly-send-an-image-to-cloudkit-as-ckasset

Comment: Hello thank you for responding @k-thorat, however I'm having trouble implementing the solutions from your answer.  They seem to be using swift and not swiftui?

Comment: also some of the items in the answers may be outdated as I'm getting error messages trying to use them.

Comment: did you try CKAsset(fileURL: url) in the AppUser init?

Comment: Yes I tried that but end up with an error stating the file path doesn’t exist @johnelemans

Comment: well, that's the problem then, not cloudkit. do a test with a file that you have on your desktop or something else simple.